# Как составить регулярное выражение для получения символов с конца строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть следующие строки:

```
C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\dtarchive\___mst__book_of_mostbet_lps\ag
C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\dtarchive\___mst__book_of_mostbet_lps\ru
C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\dtarchive\___mst__book_of_mostbet_lps\en
C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\dtarchive\___mst__book_of_mostbet_lps\pt
C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\dtarchive\___mst__book_of_mostbet_lps\ar_ma
C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\dtarchive\___mst__book_of_mostbet_lps\in_tp
```

Как из строки с помощью регулярного выражения получить последние символы (`ag`, `ru`, `en`, `pt`, `ar_ma`, `in_tp`) из конца строки?

Comment: `[^\\]*$`. Что-то такое.